# Could not set class path variable error in eclipse when trying to add new variable in classpath

Tags: eclipse-classpath

I am trying to add a new variable in classpath in eclipse.Right click on project -- > Build Path --> Configure Build Path --> Libraries Tab.
   From the right button panel,I selected Add Variable --> Configure Variables -->New.I am adding a new variable and when then eclipse gives a popup asking to have rebuild for changes to take effect.When I click OK,i get error 'Could Not Set Class Path Variables..See error logs for more details'.I checked in 'Error Log,I found:'Internal Error'.Double cliking on it Shows below exception:
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 0] PWMATRIX_HOME variable is not defined!
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2887)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1877)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2798)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2674)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2838)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1943)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getChildren(JavaElement.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:1831)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.getSelectedPackageFragmentRoot(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.updateEnabledState(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.libaryPageSelectionChanged(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.access$1(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage$LibrariesAdapter.selectionChanged(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.doListSelected(TreeListDialogField.java:924)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField$TreeViewerAdapter.selectionChanged(TreeListDialogField.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.newsourcepage.ConfigureBuildPathAction.run(ConfigureBuildPathAction.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: PWMATRIX_HOME variable is not defined!
    at com.ssc.cdt.eclipse.initializers.WSFContainerInitializer.getExtraAttrubutes(WSFContainerInitializer.java:146)
    at com.ssc.cdt.eclipse.initializers.WSFContainerInitializer.getCloudFrameworkJars(WSFContainerInitializer.java:178)
    at com.ssc.cdt.eclipse.initializers.WSFContainerInitializer.initialize(WSFContainerInitializer.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2863)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1877)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2798)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2674)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2838)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1943)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getChildren(JavaElement.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:1831)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.getSelectedPackageFragmentRoot(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.updateEnabledState(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.libaryPageSelectionChanged(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage.access$1(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.LibrariesWorkbookPage$LibrariesAdapter.selectionChanged(LibrariesWorkbookPage.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField.doListSelected(TreeListDialogField.java:924)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.TreeListDialogField$TreeViewerAdapter.selectionChanged(TreeListDialogField.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.buildpaths.newsourcepage.ConfigureBuildPathAction.run(ConfigureBuildPathAction.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
I am not able to get why these exceptions are occurring and how to resolve it.
Expecting a solution.thanks.

Comment: PWMATRIX_HOME is a variable name that I want to add and while adding this only I am getting error.

Comment: Please edit the question ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Try setting them from Window --> Preference --> Classpath Variables. Close your project folders before that.